# CSS Centre a bunch of images within a div

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to center the images within a div on my page.

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="imgblock">
        <div class="basket slide1"><a href="#">
          <div class="images">
            <div class="img-wrap"><img src="images/basket.jpg" alt="" align="center"/ </div>
            <div class="infos"></div>
          </div>
          </a></div>
        <div class="steak slide2"><a href="#">
          <div class="images">
            <div class="img-wrap"><img src="images/steak.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="infos"></div>
          </div>
          </a></div>
        <div class="col1-4 slide3"><a href="#">
          <div class="images">
            <div class="img-wrap"><img src="images/breakfast.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="infos"></div>
          </div>
          </a></div>
        <div class="fish slide4"><a href="#">
          <div class="images">
            <div class="img-wrap"><img src="images/fish.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="infos"></div>
          </div>
          </a></div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.imgblock {
width:940px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
margin:0 10px;
}
```

In my research I was told to add text-align:center and vertical-align:middle. This didn't work, I also tried margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your image are floatting, you can only reduce width of `.imgblock` and use auto margin :

```
.imgblock {
width:830px;
margin:0 auto;;
}
```

Comment: This would correctly center the container div. If the images themselves are not equal width, they would be 'jagged'.

Comment: i believe he is using a grid system to size image before sending them online, to have image sizes that fits together :)

Comment: My bad, I am just checking the example. Impressive stuff if you have limited CSS knowledge BTW, but I am guessing he is editing a template.

Answer (score 1):

As @mdesdev has said, the recommended way to center block items is through:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

That goes for your images as well. I would do something like this (untested):

```
.imgblock img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You could probably do without some of the surrounding div's as well.

Comment: can I ask which divs you think I should remove?

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
.basket {
    margin: 0 10px 0 320px;
    width: 300px;
}
```